# Change plane.firstmaterial in ARkit

Tags: ios, xcode, arkit, plane

I have implemented an image recognition system, when it recognizes this image, the plane with the material is superimposed.

I want that when I press a button the image is changed.

This is part of my code:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else {return nil}

    guard let paintingName = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name else {return nil}

    guard let painting = paintings[paintingName] else {return nil}


    let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)

    let firstImageDetail: UIImage = UIImage(named: namePicture)!

    if imageAnchor.referenceImage.name == "BalsaDeMedusa" {
        plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = firstImageDetail
    }
```

The button logic:

```
    @IBAction func nextDetail(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if i < detailsPicture.count - 1 {
        namePicture = detailsPicture[i+1]
        i += 1
    }
    else {
        i = 0
        namePicture = detailsPicture[i]
    }
}
```